# actionscript 3 "A term is undefined and has no properties."

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

This is my error

```
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
    at p21_fla::MainTimeline/baba()[p21_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:24]
```

This is the part that causes error :

```
variables.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, loaderIOErrorHandler);
```

This is my full code

```
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables(); 
variables.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, loaderIOErrorHandler);
var varSend:URLRequest = new URLRequest("https://gteckids.000webhostapp.com/gteckids/login.php");
varSend.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
varSend.data = variables;

function loaderIOErrorHandler(e:Event){
trace("Error loading image thumbnail");
}

var varLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader;
varLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
varLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler)

variables.Parent_Username = uname_txt.text;
    variables.ParentPassword = pass_txt.text;
    variables.sendRequest = "parse";    
    varLoader.load(varSend);

function completeHandler(event:Event):void
{


var phpVar1 = event.target.data.var1;

if(phpVar1!="No"){
    btn_ok.visible = true ;
    lis.visible = true;
parent_id.text = phpVar1;


}


else{
    btn_okw.visible = true ;
    lis1.visible = true;
}
}
```

Comment: Do not post code as an image. Paste in the full code here.

Answer (score 2):

That's right, an instance of URLVariables doesn't have such member, check the following spec: [Adobe Documentation: URLVariables](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLVariables.html). 
Add IOErrorEvent listener to your loader as follows:

```
... 
varLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, loaderIOErrorHandler);
...
```

And please, never post your code as a screenshot.

Comment: sorry this is my first time asking question here XD